# How to use QWebChannel

Tags: python-3.x, qwebchannel

I am creating an application in python code using app pycharm, displaying the interface using QWebEngineView. I don't know how to connect html code to python code, I want to be able to transmit and receive data from html code to python code.
This is my python code

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.web_view = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.web_view)
        self.load_local_web_page("testhtml.html")

    def load_local_web_page(self, relative_html_path):
        absolute_html_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), relative_html_path)
        self.web_view.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(absolute_html_path))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        msg_box = QMessageBox()
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Xác nhận")
        msg_box.setText("Bạn có muốn đóng ứng dụng?")
        msg_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        msg_box.move(self.pos().x() + self.width() - msg_box.width() + 390, self.pos().y())
        result = msg_box.exec_()
        if result == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML with SVG</title>
</head>
<body>

<svg>

</svg>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried many times following chatGPT but no success. Hope bro can help